# Two-column layout with overlay column - is flexbox usable here or do I need to work around display: inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I am building a two-column layout and I only need to support modern browsers. The two columns should fill 100% of the width of their container. Additionally, I have a third column which needs to be the same width as the left-side column and lay ontop of it.

If I did not have the need for an overlaying column then this problem would be easily solved with the use of flexbox. However, I'm not sure it is possible to tell the overlay column that it should be the same width as the flexible column underneath it. So, I am using percent-width columns which are `display: inline-block` and apply `font-size: 0` to the parent element to prevent additional spacing between the columns.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to use flexible columns to achieve this effect?
- If not, is there a more appropriate way to achieve this effect? I hate working around the implicit spacing of `display: inline-block` with `font-size: 0`

Is there a more appropriate way to achieve my effect in modern browsers?

[Here's my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qh849b/5/)

```
<div class='page'>
    <div class='left column'>
    </div>
    <div class='left column overlay'>
    </div>
    <div class='right column'>
    </div>
</div>

.page {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.column {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.left {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: green;
}

.right {
    width: 40%;   
    background-color: blue;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/bluedao/su28zxea/

Code from fiddle

```
<div class="row-outer">
    <div class="row-inner">
        <div class="col col1">
            <div class="overlay">
                <span>Overlay</span>
            </div>
            <div>some text</div>
            <div>some more text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col2">
            <div>Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.row-outer {
    position: absolute;
    background: gray;
    width: 100%;
}

.row-inner {
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
}

.col {
    float: left;
}

.col1 {
    background: red;
    width: 40%;
}

.col2 {
    background: blue;
    width: 60%;

}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: My JSFiddle shows the layout I'm hoping to achieve. If you toggle off the display: none on the overlay you'll see a yellow rectangle cover the left column. I'm just wondering if it possible to achieve with flexbox.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed your fiddle. I think what I've updated it to should work for you now.